# How to requery a query t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the columns: `ParentID`, `UnitName`, and `OrganizationLevelID`. `UnitName` is the name of an **account** if `OrganizationLevelID=1` and it's the name of a **site** when `OrganizationLevelID=2`. I'm trying to query for the site and then based on those site's ParentID's, query for the account. I've been trying to use the subquery below but it returns only NULL in the account column.

My current Query:

```
    SELECT t1.ParentID,
           t1.UnitName,
           (SELECT t2.UnitName
            FROM Organization t2
            WHERE t2.ParentID=t1.ParentID
            AND t2.OrganizationLevelID=1)
    FROM Organization t1
    WHERE OrganizationLevelID=2;
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe a recursive cte? It is hard to tell because we have no idea what your table structure is or what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there any record present for `WHERE t2.ParentID=t1.ParentID
            AND t2.OrganizationLevelID=1`

Comment: Could you include some sample records, and show us the output you would expect from that sample?

Answer (score 1):

you are getting null because in your outer query `WHERE OrganizationLevelID=2` 
condition
filtering the data which only returns the ParentID of only  sites
so your query will be
you have to remove `WHERE OrganizationLevelID=2` from your query

Comment: That makes sense. Would you be able to provide an example of what this query would look like because I still need to return both site and account columns.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
CREATE TABLE #Orgs (ParentId INT, UnitName NVARCHAR(20), OrgLevelId INT)

INSERT  INTO #Orgs ( ParentId , UnitName , OrgLevelId )
        SELECT  1 , 'Acc Name' , 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 , 'SITE 1' , 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 , 'SITE 2' , 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 , 'SITE 3' , 2

SELECT  t1.ParentId ,
        t1.UnitName ,
        t2.UnitName AS SiteName
FROM    #Orgs t1
        -- joins to self but with org level = 2
        INNER JOIN #Orgs t2 ON t2.ParentId = t1.ParentId
                               AND t2.OrgLevelId = 2
WHERE   t1.OrgLevelId = 1;

DROP TABLE #Orgs
```

Returns:

```
ParentID    UnitName    SiteName
1           Acc Name    SITE 1
1           Acc Name    SITE 2
1           Acc Name    SITE 3
```

Note: only works with 2 levels, you didn't mention if there were any more levels than 2.